# How to convert protocol buffers List<Integer> to String

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a service which store UUID in protocol buffer's repeated uint32 field (binary encoded id).
How to convert this (after decoding to List) back to String/UUID?

Comment: Do you have any expected input/output examples?

Comment: @MarcGravell
I don't have encoded list of Ints now. I need to prepare this for future communication between servers. I know, that input will be binary encoded UUID: "2d931510-d99f-494a-8c67-87feb05e1594". Protocol Buffer returns four Int32 in List<Integer> form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what endianness you're getting in the protobuf list, but something like this should work:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * 4);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

for (Integer i : intList) {
    buffer.putInt(i);
}

buffer.flip();
return new UUID(buffer.getLong(0), buffer.getLong(8));
```